# How to specify bot and client scopes in Slack OAuth request

Tags: slack-api, slack

When I use `client` and `bot` scopes together I get the following error.

```
https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=bot,client

Cannot request service scope (bot) with deprecated scopes.
```

It looks like the client scope is deprecated(even though I haven't seen any documentation for it). I can specify object scopes with the `bot` scope,
but I am not able to gather all the scopes that constitutes the compound scope `client`(especially the scopes for RTM).

Comment: Edit your post with your http call

Comment: @Gearnode added the url.

Comment: You don't need client scope bot scope include RTM access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client scope is not deprecated, [but is incompatible with the bot scope](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes)

> Please note that certain scopes cannot be asked for in combination
> with each other. For instance, you cannot request both the bot scope
> and the client scope. When users arrive at an authorization page
> requesting invalid scope combinations, they'll see an ugly error
> stating something to this effect:
>
> "OAuth error: invalid_scope: Cannot request service scope (bot) with deprecated scopes"

If you want to access the RTM API to build a client, request the client scope. If it is to build a Slack app using the RTM API, use the bot scope. Either one should be enough for your needs

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your own server redirect uri in the slack oauth settings by going to https://api.slack.com/applications and choosing the application you're working with.

If you're developing on local, you should request via something like  `http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorize?scope=bot,client`

Or if you're on prod, you want to specify your server uri like `http://<SERVER_URI>/oauth/authorize?scope=bot,client`